# Magento 2. Diffrent menu options for different store views

Tags: magento2, multistore, category-tree

Going through this. https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-scope.html

I found this

**Because the specific menu options are defined at the store view level, each view can have a different main menu based on the same root category**

Can someone tell me how can I have a different main menu, in two different store views under the same store based on the same root category?

Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the category-setting "show in navigation" to "yes" or "no" per store view depending on your needs.